# what wrong with this regex or is debuggex reliable?

Tags: regular-expression

I am doing a simple regex test on the below site but it says no match.

pattern = `aaaa` and search string is `fhaaaaaaachoeore` (some random string).

But the below site says - no match. Where is the problem.

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ao9CtSZ7VFpCeLr8)

Comment: The site has a very dumb user interface. It highlights the match in yellow, but you have to drag the Start and Position controls onto the match to get it to confirm in the text message. It also does not seem to know (or care) about ERE patterns. Best avoided.

Answer (score 3):

What's giving you issues is just the somewhat unintuitive user interface of the web page.  You are supposed to drag the left part of the slider from the "start" position towards the right.  When the "start" position coincides with the start of the match, it will say "Matches" in green text. Note that the actual match is highlighted in yellow (at least I believe it is, the sizes of the characters and their spacing is a bit strange). I honestly don't know how useful that is.

Another way for you to test this using a standard Unix command-line tool is this:

```bsh
echo 'fhaaaaaaachoeore' | sed 's/aaaa/(&)/g'
```

The above would use the `sed` utility to substitute all matches of the regular expression `aaaa` with itself in parentheses.

Testing on the command line:

```bsh
$ echo 'fhaaaaaaachoeore' | sed 's/aaaa/(&)/g'
fh(aaaa)aaachoeore
```

Or, using an expression that matches all characters that are repeated  consecutively more than once,

```bsh
$ echo 'fhaaaaaaachoeooore' | sed 's/\(.\)\1\{1,\}/(&)/g'
fh(aaaaaaa)choe(ooo)re
```

Comment: "_You are supposed to drag the left part of the slider from the "start" position towards the right_" I saw that made the RE match. But why would someone want to drag the slider? It's like the website doesn't understand `^` (but it does). (+1 for the `sed` demo.)

Comment: @roaima Shrug. Somebody didn't test the site on others than themselves?

Comment: What the slider does (for a more complex RE) is to highlight which parts of the RE match which parts of the text. It does this both in the text, and in diagrammatic form in the top box.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Ah, yes. Well, it's a bit awkward to use.  It may well be useful to someone that knows how to use it. In any case, the site and its UI is not really on-topic here, which is why I tried to show another way to play around with regular expressions that would be more suitable for this site.

Comment: @they  Absolutely. Your sed visualisers knocked my socks off.

Answer (score 1):

The website appears to be faulty. An un-anchored Regular Expression pattern of `aaaa` will match on the string `fhaaaaaaachoeore`.